# Collapsing toolbar using navigation components

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm creating an application that uses the `Jetpack navigation Components` with multiple fragments and single activity.

The activity contains the FragmentContainerView in addition to the `AppBar` which includes only a `Toolbar` that is supposed to be shared between all fragments.

Now what I'm trying to do is to use a `Collapsing Toolbar` in one of these fragments with an Image to view some details, and make a shared element transition to it.

Is it possible to implement that?

Answer (score 1):

In the themes, set the theme as NoActionBar

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"> <!-- changed .DarkActionBar to .NoActionBar -->
   <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
   <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
   <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
   <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Then add a toolbar in each fragment.

You can have a Toolbar or a CollapsingToolbar depending on your need.

Follow the links to check on implementing the Collapsing toolbar

[Expanding And Collapsing Toolbar In Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276361/expanding-and-collapsing-toolbar-in-android)

Comment: How if i use NoActionBar only for one fragment, and i need toolbar in other fragment?

Comment: Are you using the jetpack navigation library? link: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation

Comment: yes, i use jetpack navigation

Comment: Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60941129/9414276) or post a question so I can help you in a better way.